# Does Oracle server installation include client components?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation, linked-server, client

I installed Oracle personal edition on a Windows Server 2008 virtual machine for testing purposes. My intention is to test Linked server functionality with SQL Server. Does Oracle Server installation include also client components?

Comment: Yes, it does include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does, as @Phil said in the comment.